# How do I fix a "Unknown configuration key `foreign-architecture' found in your `dpkg' configuration files." error?

Tags: command-line, dpkg, multiarch

Always when I install something, I get the following error multiple times:

> Unknown configuration key 'foreign-architecture' found in your 'dpkg'
>   configuration files.  This warning will become a hard error at a later
>   date, so please remove the offending configuration options and replace
>   them with 'dpkg --add-architecture' invocations at the command line.

When I try `dpkg --add-architecture` I get:

```
Unknown configuration key `foreign-architecture' found in your `dpkg'
configuration files.  This warning will become a hard error at a later
date, so please remove the offending configuration options and replace
them with `dpkg --add-architecture' invocations at the command line.

dpkg: error: --add-architecture takes one argument

Type dpkg --help for help about installing and deinstalling packages [*];
Use `dselect' or `aptitude' for user-friendly package management;
Type dpkg -Dhelp for a list of dpkg debug flag values;
Type dpkg --force-help for a list of forcing options;
Type dpkg-deb --help for help about manipulating *.deb files;

Options marked [*] produce a lot of output - pipe it through `less' or `more' !
```

I've no problems yet, but since it says **This warning will become a hard error at a later date** I better do something about this. When I search 'foreign-architecture', I find an empty file, containing not a single byte. I somehow can't delete that file.

Please help, it's a kind of creapy...

I use Ubuntu version 12.10

Updated the questions:

```
cat /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg 
no-debsig 
log /var/log/dpkg.log

ls /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/
multiarch
```

Comment: Post the results of `cat /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg` & `ls /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/` . Re-edit your question.

Comment: for cat:

# dpkg configuration file
#
# This file can contain default options for dpkg.  All command-line
# options are allowed.  Values can be specified by putting them after
# the option, separated by whitespace and/or an `=' sign.
#

# Do not enable debsig-verify by default; since the distribution is not using
# embedded signatures, debsig-verify would reject all packages.
no-debsig

# Log status changes and actions to a file.
log /var/log/dpkg.log

For ls: multiarch

Comment: Please edit your question and add the results between code tags. Cannot read anything like that.

Comment: Please update the question with the following information: Ubuntu version, architecture (`uname -m`) and the oputput of `cat /var/lib/dpkg/arch`.

Comment: sorr, what do you mean with 'architecture (uname -m)'? and cat /var/lib/dpkg/arch gives: No such file or directory. I don't think I have to write that down? By the way, if you want to edit, just do it.

Comment: Open a terminal window and enter: `uname -m` and it will give the CPU architecture (ex: `i686` for a Pentium 4).

Comment: Is your question still unanswered? If yes please provide  the contents of the file `/etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch`.

Comment: I have encountered same problem, so I edited the question with wanted information

Answer (score 7):

You say in the comments that you see:

```
$ ls /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/
multiarch
```

Presumably that file, `/etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch`, contains a `foreign-architecture` key. So I suggest just deleting the file:

```
sudo rm /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch
```

Comment: As you've said in [another comment](http://askubuntu.com/questions/238006/why-does-my-64-bit-system-look-for-32-bit-repos/238043#comment296714_238043) this file is not being used anymore on 12.10. I assume this is just a leftover from the upgrade from 12.04 of the OP.

Comment: It should have been cleaned up on upgrade

Answer (score 3):

My `/etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch` contained:

```
foreign-architecture i386
```

I deleted the file.  I then issued:

```
dpkg --add-architecture foreign-architecture
```

Comment: then what's happened?