# Unable to install Synaptic Package Manager

Tags: apt, server, package-management, application-development, synaptic

I am unable to install the "synaptic Package Manager" from Ubuntu software store. I am using Ubuntu 23.04, while I am trying to install it the dialog shows" unable to install "Synaptic Package Manager" error while running the transaction

[image]

---

I followed this instruction and the result is as follows:

```
ramendu-narayan-datta@ramendu-narayan-datta-AM1M-S2H:~$ sudo apt-get install --yes synaptic
[sudo] password for ramendu-narayan-datta: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libept1.6.0 libxapian30
Suggested packages:
  xapian-tools dwww deborphan apt-xapian-index tasksel
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libept1.6.0 libxapian30 synaptic
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,363 kB of archives.
After this operation, 5,282 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar/universe amd64 libept1.6.0 amd64 1.2.1 [84.1 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar/universe amd64 libxapian30 amd64 1.4.22-1 [694 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar/universe amd64 synaptic amd64 0.91.3 [585 kB]
Fetched 1,363 kB in 2s (588 kB/s) 
dpkg: error: configuration error: /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch:1: unknown option 'foreign-architecture'
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
ramendu-narayan-datta@ramendu-narayan-datta-AM1M-S2H:~$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-6.2.0-26 linux-headers-6.2.0-26-generic
  linux-image-6.2.0-26-generic linux-modules-6.2.0-26-generic
  linux-modules-extra-6.2.0-26-generic
The following packages will be upgraded:
  linux-generic-hwe-22.04 linux-headers-generic-hwe-22.04
  linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04 linux-libc-dev openssh-client
5 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
5 standard LTS security updates
Need to get 0 B/141 MB of archives.
After this operation, 808 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
dpkg: error: configuration error: /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch:1: unknown opti
on 'foreign-architecture'
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
ramendu-narayan-datta@ramendu-narayan-datta-AM1M-S2H:~$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-security InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar InRelease
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-updates InRelease
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-security InRelease
Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-backports InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
5 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
ramendu-narayan-datta@ramendu-narayan-datta-AM1M-S2H:~$
```

Comment: Try to install the manager in the console and [add](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1479388/edit) the output to your question: `sudo apt-get install --yes synaptic`

Comment: you didn't say how you tried to install Synaptic. I just installed it from Ubuntu Software in version 23.04 with Gnome version 44.2 under X11 windowing system and it installed perfectly well with no errors noted.

Comment: Please check https://askubuntu.com/questions/230952/how-do-i-fix-a-unknown-configuration-key-foreign-architecture-found-in-your

Comment: It looks like you made a mistake in the past when adding an architecture. Please edit your post (do not post a separate answer, *edit your post*), and include the output of `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures`

Answer (score 0):

It is learnt from various source that ubuntu 23.04 not LTS version and it has many bugs so I decided to complete uninstall ubuntu 23.04 and install 22.04LTS alongside Windows 10, And it is seen that Epson l360 printer and scanner have smoothly installed and working fine .
This is for information for every one